# Javascript countdown with users input

Tags: javascript, input

Hello im trying to make simple app which counts down numbers from input to 0 every 1 second. Can somebody explain me what im doing wrong with my code pls? I tried different combinations of setTimeOut and countDown functions but in the best set up my app was able only to show numbers from input(#number) to 0 for only a moment. i dont know why even console is being cleared every time after i click ,,start".

```
<body>


    <form>
        <h1>Countdown:</h1>
        <h3>Set time</h3>
        <input id="number" type="text">
        <button id="start">Start</button>
    </form>
    <div id="area"><p id="text1"></p></div>
<script>
        window.onload = init;
        function init(){
            var start = document.getElementById("start");
            start.onclick = finalCountDown;
        }

         function finalCountDown() {setTimeout(countDown,1000);}
        function countDown(){
            console.log("works");
            var number = document.getElementById("number");
            var value = number.value;
            var area = document.getElementById("text1");
            for (var i = value; i>0;i--){
            area.innerHTML+=i;
            }
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: what error are you encountering i think it may be because of concatenation

Comment: try area.innerHTML -= -Number(i)

Comment: still html shows nothing. there are no errors in console. just nothing appears on the screen

Comment: i encountered a similar error yesterday is the html only changing once? also what tag type is area

Comment: yes. there are no uploads of numbers

Answer (score 0):

Few problems here;

1. On your button you need to set the attribute type="button" or it will try to submit your form.
2. In your setTimeout you reference the `countDown` function but never invoke it. You need to write `setTimeout(countDown(), 1000);`.

```js
window.onload = init;
function init(){
    var start = document.getElementById("start");
    start.onclick = finalCountDown;
}

 function finalCountDown() {setTimeout(countDown(),1000);}
function countDown(){
    console.log("works");
    var number = document.getElementById("number");
    var value = number.value;
    var area = document.getElementById("text1");
    for (var i = value; i>0;i--){
    area.innerHTML+=i;
    }
}
```

```html
<form>
    <h1>Countdown:</h1>
    <h3>Set time</h3>
    <input id="number" type="text">
    <button type="button" id="start">Start</button>
</form>
<div id="area"><p id="text1"></p></div>
```

Doing this will remove the errors from your code. Now you just need to change some things around to get the desired result as follows:

```js
window.onload = init;
function init(){
    var start = document.getElementById("start");
    start.onclick = finalCountDown;
}

function finalCountDown() {setTimeout(countDown(),1000);}

function countDown(){
    console.log("works");
    var number = document.getElementById("number");
    var value = parseInt(number.value, 10);
    var area = document.getElementById("text1");
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (value > -1) {
            area.innerText = value;
            value--;
        } else {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<form>
    <h1>Countdown:</h1>
    <h3>Set time</h3>
    <input id="number" type="text">
    <button type="button" id="start">Start</button>
</form>
<div id="area"><p id="text1"></p></div>
```

I'm not sure if you are interested in the 1 second delay caused by setTimeout before it starts counting down or if that was just a mistake. I'm assuming the latter, if so just remove that function and it's invocation. Replace it with countDown.

In response to your comment, instead of taking a `<p>` element and updating its `.innerText`, you could replace the `<p>` with a `<ul>`. I'd give the `<ul>` a more contextual `<id>` attribute and replace the `var area = ...` with a variable referencing the new `<ul>`. Next you should replace `area.innerText...` with something like:

```
var li = document.createElement("LI");
li.innerText = i;
ul.appendChild(li);
```

Snippet for full picture:

```js
window.onload = init;
function init(){
    var start = document.getElementById("start");
    start.onclick = finalCountDown;
}

function finalCountDown() {setTimeout(countDown(),1000);}

function countDown(){
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById("number").value, 10);
    var ul = document.getElementById("ul");
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (value > -1) {
            var li = document.createElement("LI");
            li.innerText = value;
            ul.appendChild(li);
            value--;
        } else {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<form>
    <h1>Countdown:</h1>
    <h3>Set time</h3>
    <input id="number" type="text">
    <button type="button" id="start">Start</button>
</form>
<ul id="ul"></ul>
```

Comment: thank you so much! if i can have one more question - what if id like to have all numbers (10->0) written one after another or in a list?

Comment: You're welcome. I'll add that to my answer when I get back to a pc. Please accept answer.